# GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter (Android Places API) returning results outside of boundary

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

It seems that the sample code from Google that demonstrates the Google Places API for Android is returning results from outside of the given boundary. (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/).

Searching for 'hardware' shows most results from Sydney (the hardcoded boundary), but also (occasionally) shows results from as far away as other cities (including Western Australia!). I've implemented GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter in my own code and have found similar results. It seems that the Boundary field is only a guideline for the search; can anyone confirm this?

This may or may not be related, but does anyone know also whether the results returned from Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions are the same results that can be expected from a similar call to the Web Services Places API? With a few tests it seems the web services call returns better results (closer to location, more relevant, and overall more results). The API docs do not seem to shed any light on this -- my guess is perhaps the getAutocompletePredictions query is performed on the 'name' of the Place rather than in a 'keyword' search as per the web service API implementation.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#getAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter)), the bounds is...

> for geographically biasing the autocomplete predictions.

This means exactly what you suggested. Results inside are preferred, but not required.